# Dynamic BLE Advertisements Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any way I can use Bluetooth Low Energy to advertise data that changes? For example, incrementing a value in the advertising data every time the advertisement has been sent out?

Answer (score 1):

The only available API is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html.

That API and the Bluetooth standard itself includes no way to change advertisement data on each advertisement packet. If you want to change advertisement data you have to stop the ongoing advertisement and start a new advertisement with different data.

Comment: Hmm that's what I was hoping to avoid... Is there a way to ensure only one packet is advertised?

Comment: No. What are you trying to build? Why is it important only one packet is sent? When the other side receives a packet it can just drop it if it sees that it is the same data as in last packet.

Comment: The advertisement value was written to link layer in the Bluetooth firmware and can not be changed dynamically except like @Emil said you stop/start advertisement again. However if you have firmware code(this is the code below HCI level) you may implement it; but these code all belongs to chip vendors and may not public.